# dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading

Tags: unity

I get the following error after installing nmap:

```
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Try installing zenmap from the software centre it will automatically install nmap

Answer (score 5):

#### Missing *available* file

My *available* and *available-old* was both empty.

I've successfully resolved from this by running:

```
cat /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages >/var/lib/dpkg/available
dpkg --configure -a
```

Or using `sudo`

```
cat /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages | sudo dd of=/var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Did not work for me, though this is an interesting answer.

Comment: This worked for me, which is ok, since I’m only working in a throwaway environment, with this problem.

Comment: For those using sudo: `cat /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages | sudo tee /var/lib/dpkg/available 1>/dev/null`

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following, one line at a time:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This should repair/recreate your `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file.

[(Source)](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/55616)

Comment: Show de bola!!!

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
```

The above error clearly shows that the file `available` in the directory `/var/lib/dpkg` is missing. Don't worry about that. There will be a backup for all the files inside `/var/lib/dpkg` directory is located on the same directory itself. So just renaming or copying the backup file would solve your problem.

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

This will create a new file called `available` on the same directory. Please note that `dpkg` will only look for the file `/var/lib/dpkg/available` and not `/var/lib/dpkg/available-old`.

Comment: and you should mention re-configuring or re-installing nmap as `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or  `sudo apt install --reinstall nmap` after the above operation :)

Comment: Did not work for me.